# double select within a insert sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

```
Persons (PersonID, LastName, FirstName)
Orders (O_Id, OrderNo, P_Id)
```

`Orders.P_Id` should have values from `Persons.PersonID`.

I am trying to do an insert on Orders to insert the P_Id into orders but I want it to match a value in my Persons table and also my Orders table so I can link them up and allow the P_id to be linked to the order.

I have tried this below? not sure what the best way to do this would be?

```
INSERT INTO Orders (P_Id)
SELECT PersonID FROM Persons
WHERE PersonID='1'
UNION ALL
SELECT O_Id FROM Orders
WHERE O_Id ='1';
```

---

Edit:
I have tried UNION ALL but it doesn't add them on the same line here is my sql fiddle which shows what is happening:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/30a71/1

anyone help?

Comment: Are you looking for a `JOIN`?

Comment: Your query doesn't make any sense (even with syntax issues fixed). What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: have a look at my sql fiddle @Bohemian http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/30a71/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to *UPDATE* (not INSERT):

```
UPDATE ORDERS SET
P_Id = 1
WHERE O_Id = 1;
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e6ec6/1)

Comment: that worked great is there a neater way to INSERT the orders details but update the p_id (so i have a reference) all in 1 query? @Bohemian

Comment: @user4058171 no, because there's no way to know the details of the order without actually coding the values as literals.

Comment: ok thanks for the advice, so if i ever wanted to link my order table with my person table i would have to insert the values of the order and then update the P_id table in orders to allow it to ever sync? @Bohemian

Comment: Your order table is .*already* linked to your person table: you have a foreign key from orders to person via p_id.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're actually trying to achieve is not through the form of an `INSERT`, but an `UPDATE`:

Try this:

```
UPDATE Orders
SET P_ID = (SELECT PersonID From Persons WHERE PersonID = 1)
WHERE O_ID = 1
```

You can't "`INSERT`" a value into an existing row with a `INSERT` command. For that reason the `UPDATE` command exists.

The `INSERT` is useful only when creating a row in the table. For all other scenarios, when you are trying to populate a column with data, into an existing row, then you should use `UPDATE`.

The above query is basically a re-write of what you have, but since you already know the value of PersonID which you want to populate the P_ID column with, then you can simplify the query to:

```
UPDATE Orders
SET P_Id = 1
WHERE O_Id = 1
```

Comment: that worked great is there a neater way to INSERT the orders details but update the p_id (so i have a reference) all in 1 query?